# Securitydb.mdw security issues

Tags: security, ms-access, jet

I have an MS ACCESS 2003 database which uses a shortcut, and a securitydb.mdw file. My understanding is that the securitydb.mdw file does something special to the registry of the computer and checks for a user and workgroup?

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Database\database.MDB" /x STARTUP /wrkgrp "C:\Database\securitydb.mdw"
```

I would like to have access to the database but cant as its asking for a username and password. It works fine on there network, just not outside.

I am using Win 7 x64 and MS ACCESS 2010. How can i remove the security from the database so i can get access to the system? I need to write a function spec based on this and the customer is not available.

Comment: Do you have a username and password?

Comment: No this is why i want to get into the system.

Comment: As there is no user specified in the command line, I believe it will attempt to run with the default 'Admin' username, likelihood is whoever originally created the mdw file would have either set a password or removed permissions for this username for security issues.  If you have not been given the login details then you quite rightly will not gain access to this database file.

Comment: There are a number of inexpensive MS-Access password retrieval applications that will reveal the user/password. Google "access password recovery".

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately i cant ask any more questions on my account? Can i modderator or admin fix this please?